# Display time as DD.MM.YY

Tags: python

I can currently convert it to DD.MM.YYYY this with

```
timestr = time.strftime("%d.%m.%y")
```

However, I'm struggling with this format DD.MM.YY

Comment: I suggest reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: Find a programmer older than about 40, and ask them about the wisdom of this. :)

Comment: @TurePålsson sorry, did not get that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will print `timestr` in format DD.MM.YYYY

```
timestr = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
```

> '16.07.2021'

If you change `%Y` to `%y`, you will have it DD.MM.YY

```
timestr = time.strftime("%d.%m.%y")
```

> '16.07.21'

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` could help

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(2021,7,16)
dt.strftime('%d.%m.%y')
```

yields

> '16.07.21'

Comment: Drop the leading `0` and it is fine.

Comment: thanks. it looks much prettier here but makes no difference in code.

Comment: It makes a difference: `SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers`

Comment: indeed, for python3.x it makes a difference. python2.7 swallows it silently.

Comment: You should upgrade.

Comment: not really. i have one hell LOCs of legacy code in py2.7